# Why does util.inherits create a new object that inherits from the super constructor's prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype

In [the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L634-L644) for `util.inherits` they call `object.create` to create a new object whose prototype is the prototype of the super constructor.

```
ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: ctor,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
```

Why is this? Why not just do:

```
ctor.prototype = superCtr.prototype?
```

Comment: That's how prototypical inheritance works. `.prototype != [[Prototype]]`. `Object.create` sets the internal property.

Comment: thats just an assingment.

Comment: @DanielA.White Isn't the way they do it pretty much just an assignment too? They just create a new object whose prototype is the one we're after, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why not just do: ctor.prototype = superCtr.prototype?

This would mean that whenever someone adds methods to `ctor.prototype`, they also end up adding methods to `superCtr.prototype`, since they are the same object.

That would be horrible! It would mean that if you have e.g. `http.IncomingMessage` inheriting from `EventEmitter`, then every method on `http.IncomingMessage.prototype` would end up on `EventEmitter.prototype`. Thus, every event emitter in all of io.js would have HTTP-related methods on it!

Instead, we create a new object which we can add methods to that are specific to `ctor` instances. Since we ensure that that new object is `Object.create`d from `superCtor.prototype`, we know that any lookups against that object will follow the [[Prototype]]-chain and find methods from `superCtor.prototype`, as you'd expect when doing inheritance. But it's a new object with space for its own customization, as you'd desire.